# Need help in C++ with allegro library....?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, allegro

I installed CodeBlocks 10.5 with minGW compiler. After setting environment variables for minGW I cheked gcc -v on cmd and it is working fine. 
The problem is that, I have made a small program in CodeBlocks project the code is below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

There is an error, the build log is:

Compiling: main.cpp
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\allegro_pract… error: allegro5/allegro.h: No such file or directory
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
1 errors, 0 warnings

Directory structure for codeblocks is:
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks
and for minGW:
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\mingw
and my project is:
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\bin\

i am confused about allegro library where to place it.. as I have not used any external library..
the library is placed now at:
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\mingw\allegro\

I am "Googling" for a long time but no tutorial seems to be working..
please give a valid solution.. and where to place allegro library..??

Comment: Does CodeBlocks support unix style slashes ? front slashes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not try to "place" libraries in the "right place". Instead, tell the IDE where you put them explicitly. This is called setting the include path.

Code::Blocks should have some setting for include directories. You should point it to the place where Allegro lives.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You're in charge, you tell the damn compiler where to find allegro.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your IDE to look for Allegro:

[image]
<sub>(source: [allegro.cc](http://wiki.allegro.cc/pub/thumb/d/da/Relative.jpg/400px-Relative.jpg))</sub>

The complete tutorial is here:

- http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Windows,_Code::Blocks_10.05_and_Allegro_5

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mingw.org/wiki/IncludePathHOWTO:

> The actual search path, for any specific installation of MinGW may be determined, by running the compiler itself, with the "-v" option; typically, for a GCC-3.4.5 installation in c:/mingw:--

defaults appear to be:

> c:/mingw/include/c++/3.4.5
>   c:/mingw/include/c++/3.4.5/mingw32
>   c:/mingw/include/c++/3.4.5/backward
>   c:/mingw/include
>   c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/include

I don't use mingw, so, read the link.